# Native Build Failing using gradle

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, gradle

I am trying to move from gradle to maven. Here is my simple hello world example build. My gradle.build is as follows :-

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

model {
    components {
    main(NativeExecutableSpec) {}
  }
}
```

I have a cpp file and an h file. The directory structure is as the follows :-

```
src/main/cpp/HelloWorld.cpp
src/main/headers/HelloWorld.h
```

My header file is as the follows :-

```
// Hello.h

#if defined(_WIN32) && defined(DLL_EXPORT)
#define LIB_FUNC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB_FUNC
#endif

class LIB_FUNC Hello
{
    private:
        const char * who;
    public:
        Hello(const char * who);
        void sayHello(unsigned n = 1);
};
```

and my source is as follows:-

```
// main.cpp
#include "Hello.h"
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Hello hello ("Pepito");
    hello.sayHello(10);
    return 0;
}
```

When i try to run gradle installMainExecutable the following error :-

```
HelloWorld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Hello::Hello(char const *)" (??0Hello@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function _main
HelloWorld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Hello::sayHello(unsigned int)" (?sayHello@Hello@@QAEXI@Z) referenced in function _main
```

I am using visual studio 2012 and whatever cl.exe comes with it. I asked my friend to compile in clang++ in OSx and it worked for him. I dont know whats wrong. Can someone help?

My gradle version:-

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-05-05 08:09:24 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     5c9c3bc20ca1c281ac7972643f1e2d190f2c943c

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
JVM:          1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

The definition of the DLL_EXPORT symbol should be done in gradle in the following fashion:-

```
binaries.withType(NativeLibrarySpec) {
    if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
         cCompiler.args "/Zi"
         cCompiler.define "DLL_EXPORT"
    }
}
```

This would ensure visual studio picks up the correct export symbols. All symbols are exported by default in g++ and clang++ so it didnt cause much problems there. But you have to add this to assert the symbols are exported during link phase.

Thanks to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html. Everyone should read this document very thoroughly.